# opening oracle applications in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox3.6, oracleapplications

I'm using firefox 3.6 and I'm not able to open oracle applications on it. I tried the methods given on the websites such as enabling the next generation java jre plugin but still firefox crashes when I try to open oracle applications. Is there some step that I'm missing or is there anything additional that has to be done? The oracle applications version I'm using is 11.5

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do they have a "supported browsers" list and or "software requirements" page? If 3.6 isn't on it, I would switch to what they want you to use otherwise I would test it with different browsers.

Comment: firefox 3.6 is supported. http://blogs.oracle.com/stevenChan/entry/firefox_36_ebs